# When do we need the hyper prior for the Hierarchical model？

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

Just questions for that when do we need the hyper prior for the hierarchical model?

For example the first layer of the hierarchical model is $m \sim \text{dnorm}(a,b)$.

What is the difference between keep $a$, $b$ fixed and sign the $a$ and $b$ for some distributions?

Comment: If a and b are fixed, it's not a hierarchical model.

Comment: Thanks for your response. what I mean is the first layer of the hierarchical model. It may have the second layer , third layer. so the total model is Hierarchical model.